# With Babel, how do I *not* compile away class properties, since browsers support them natively now?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Given this code:

```js
class A {
  #a = 'hi';

  get #b() {
    return 'hello' + this.#a;
  }

  get c() { return this.#b; }
}
```

I can run this:

```js
let a = new A()
console.log(a.c);
```

and get `hellohi`
in both Chrome 94 and Firefox 93+
(by just typing it in to the console when the dev-tools are open).

*but*,

in the babel REPL, I am not able to get the same result.

*my browserlist is `last 1 firefox versions`*

[Example Babel REPL with the env preset](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=last%201%20firefox%20versions&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.6&spec=false&loose=true&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1oGIzQLzQOQAsBLXAbhWgHMBTAF3QCMAKASkXNQCdaBXDgOzz4qIEAHtc0ANTQaRCADoMZVAF9y1OsBaJoXGrwGzCCtPRLQ1KoA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=true&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.15.8&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D) - the output is 31 lines longer, when it shouldn't have changed at all.

Additionally, something interesting:

- [Without the preset:env](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=last%201%20firefox%20version&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.6&spec=false&loose=true&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1oGIzQLzQOQAsBLXAbhWgHMBTAF3QCMAKASkXNQCdaBXDgOzz4qIEAHtc0ANTQaRCADoMZVAF9y1OsBaJoXGrwGzCCtPRLQ1qcgBNtyVJx78Zc-cGUXy5KtkHCxpF6oAPTBAAIAZpRkKkA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=true&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.15.8&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D)
- [and then with the decorator line uncommented](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=last%201%20firefox%20version&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.6&spec=false&loose=true&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1oGIzQLzQOQAsBLXAbhWgHMBTAF3QCMAKASkXNQCdaBXDgOzz4qIEAHtc0ANTQaRCADoMZVAF9y1OsBaJoXGrwGzCCtPRLQ1qcgBNtyVJx78Zc-cGUXy5KtkHCxpF6oAAIAZpRkKkA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=true&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=stage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.15.8&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D)
  The output here is suddenly applying *all* transforms, even though, with my browserlist setting, only the one property should have transforms on it (the one with the decorator). In this example it seems that the class properties transform only supports "all or nothing"? I imagine this has a huge negative impact to build times.

My question is: **How do I convince babel to leave properties and methods alone and *not* transpile them?**

According to caniuse.com:

- All supported by both Firefox and Chrome currently (93 and 94, respectively at the time of writing):

  - [private methods](https://caniuse.com/?search=private%20method)
  - [private class fields](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_classes_private_class_fields)
  - [public class fields](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_classes_public_class_fields)
  - [static class fields](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_classes_static_class_fields)

Comment: Did you run `npx browserslist@latest --update-db`? Although that shouldn't be an issue in the playground..

Comment: Although, it seems the playground just uses preset-env, so it would need to run that command in the babel website repo to have latest browserlist entries.

Comment: I just made a reproduction over here: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/babel-transpilation-tests
and it works as expected. It seems this all comes down to updated browserlist db and the entry in package.json. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally issues with browserslist are due to you not getting the browser versions you expect. It's recommended to update the caniuse database in your project regularly to get latest browser versions for preset-env.

You can do that like so:

```
yarn add -D browserslist@latest
yarn browserslist --update-db
```

Comment: thanks! I've verified this here: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/babel-transpilation-tests

Comment: hopefully the playground folks update their stuff